# Postgres ltree Query to fetch data after the hierarchy using column name

Tags: sql, postgresql, b-tree, ltree

I wanted to fetch Postgres ltree hierarchy after certain level using subltree and column name. I am able to fetch when i provide the exact input but not able to do so with column name.

This is working fine:

```
select *
from audit.EMPLOYEE_TOTALS_BY_DAY_WITHOUT_FP_MV_V4
where ecd_path ~ '10130882.11000114.10152749.10148495.10125148.*{1,}'
  and customer_id = 2955
limit 10;
```

But this is not. Please correct me with right query

```
select *
from audit.EMPLOYEE_TOTALS_BY_DAY_WITHOUT_FP_MV_V4
where ecd_path ~ subltree(ecd_path, 0, nlevel(ecd_path)-1)'.*{1,}'
  and customer_id = 2955
limit 10;
;
```

I am very new to Postgres Ltree . Correct me if anything is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to return everything whose path is more than 5 labels deep, then it would seem that this could be accomplished by doing:

```
    select *
    from audit.EMPLOYEE_TOTALS_BY_DAY_WITHOUT_FP_MV_V4
    where nlevel(ecd_path) > 5
    and customer_id = 2955
    limit 10;
```